# How to write custom datatype (std::array filled with std::pairs) to a filestream

Tags: c++

I am quite new to c++ and I am building a model studying certain mutations in genes. My "genes" are defined as a function of two doubles, a and b. A single gene is saved in a std::pair format. The whole genome consists of four of these genes collected in a std:array.

I perform some changes on the genes and want to write the information in a text file for analysis. The way I have currently implemented this is tedious. I have separate functions (8 in total) which collect the information like g[i].first, g[i[.second etc. for every i in the array. I feel this could be done much more efficiently.

Relevant code:

Declaration of data type:

```
using gene = std::pair<double, double>;
using genome = std::array<gene, 4>;
```

Function in which I create a genome called g:

```
genome Individual::init_Individual()
{
    double a1, a2, a3, a4 = -1.0;
    double b1, b2, b3, b4 = 0.0;
    gene g1{ a1,b1 };
    gene g2{ a2,b2 };
    gene g3{ a3,b3 };
    gene g4{ a4,b4 };
    genome g{g1,g2,g3,g4};
    return g;
}
```

Example of collect function:

```
double get_Genome_a1() { return g[0].first; };
```

Function in which I write information to a text file:

```
void Individual::write_Statistics(unsigned int &counter)
{
    //Generate output file stream
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("data.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);    
    ofs << counter << std::setw(14) << get_Genome_a1() <<     std::setw(14)
        << get_Genome_a2() << std::setw(14) << get_Genome_b1() <<
        std::setw(14) << get_Genome_b2() << "\n";
}
ofs.close();
```

}

etc, etc. So the final result of my data file in this example looks like this:

1   a1    a2    b1   b2

2   a1    a2    b1   b2

3   a1    a2    b1   b2

etc, etc.

My question:

1. I am currently storing the two doubles in a std::pair, which I collect in a std::array. Is this an efficient storage mechanism or can this be improved?
2. Is there a way to directly reference an individual element from my custom data type "genome" using only one function to write every element away in the exact same manner as I am doing now (with fourteen spaces between every element)? Something in pseudocode like: get_Genome() {return g;};, and when you call it you can specify the element like: get_Genome([0].first) which would be the first value stored in the first pair of the array, for example.

Happy to learn, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: For point 2, you could define your own class (a wrapper around your 4-length array) and overload the operator [].

Comment: interesting fun fact: in `double a1, a2, a3, a4 = -1.0;`, only `a4` is initialized to -1.0. The rest are used with undefined values.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this!

Comment: _"Function in which I create a genome"_ Calling it a Factory would be better, so `genomeFactory` is more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array` looks good, however using `std::pair` in this situation might make it a bit more tedious. I would create 2 simple classes or structures one to represent a gene and the other to represent your genome. I'd still use `array`. The class might look something like this:

```
#include <array>

const int genesPerGenome = 4; // change this to set how many...

struct Gene {
    double a_;
    double b_;

    Gene() = default;
    Gene(double a, double b) : a_(a), b_(b) {}
};

struct Genome {
    std::array<Gene, genesPerGenome> genome_;
    int geneCount_{0};

    Genome() = default;

    void addGene(const Gene& gene) {
        if ( geneCount_ >= genesPerGenome ) return;
        genome_[geneCount_++] = gene; // post increment since we added one
    }
};
```

Then I would have a stand alone function that would generate your genome as such:

```
void generateGenome( Genome& genome ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // When looking at your example; I notices that the genes were all
        // initialized with [-1.0,0.0] so I used Gene's constructor to init
        // them with those values.
        Gene gene(-1.0, 0.0);
        genome.addGene(gene);
    }
}
```

Then to couple these together, I'll just print them to the console for demonstration. You can then take this approach and apply it to what ever calculations that will be done and then writing the results to a file.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Genome genome;
    generateGenome( genome );

    // printing to console here is where you would do your calculations then write to file
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        if ( i >= genome.geneCount_ ) break; // prevent accessing beyond array bounds
        std::cout << (i+1) << " [" << genome.genome_[i].a_ << "," << genome.genome_[i].b_ << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*-Output-* - No calculations, only the initialized values:

```
1 [-1,0]
2 [-1,0]
3 [-1,0]
4 [-1,0]
```

Maybe this will help. From here you can write a `operartor<<()` function that will take an `ostream` reference object and a const reference to a `Genome` and from there you should be able to print the entire Genome to file in a single function call.

*-Edit-*

User `t.niese` left a comment with a valid point that I had overlooked. I was using a static variable in the `addGene()` function. This would work okay as long as you are working only with a single Genome, but if you had more than one Genome object, every time you'd call the `addGene()` function this value would increase and you wouldn't be able to add more than `gene` to each genome due to the condition of the if statement in the `addGene()` function.

I had modified the original code above to fix this limitation. Here I removed the static variable and I introduced two new variables; one is a const int that represents how many genes per genome as it will be used to define the size of your array as well as checking against how many genes to add to that genome. The other variable I added is a member variable to the Genome class itself that keeps track of how many genes there are per each Genome object.

Comment: This looks interesting. Appreciate the feedback! Because I am not that experienced, I just tried to stick to the STL formats, but I will try to implement something like this, thank you :)

Comment: Writing `if (i > 3) return;` is not necessarily a good idea, as it would just silently ignore all further `addGene` if it was called more than `4` times. And `static int i = 0;`  is shared between all instances of `Genome` so you could not use two instances of `Genome` in one run of the application and have 4 `Gene` in each.

Comment: @t.niese I did this because the OP had 4 genes to a genome by the use of std::array... If the OP wants to add more than 4 genes to a genome he can either increase the size of the array and this limiter or he could use std::vector instead.

Comment: @FrancisCugler yes but if you would have `Genome gen1; Genome gen2;  generateGenome( gen1 );  generateGenome( gen2 );` then the `addGene` would not have any effect for  `gen2`.  As `static int i = 0;` would already be `>3` from `generateGenome( gen1 );`, `static int i = 0;`  is the same for `gen1` and `gen2`

Comment: @t.niese That's true if he's working with multiple Genomes.

Comment: @t.niese I took your advise and removed the static, I introduced a const global for how many genes / genome, and I added a geneCount variable to keep track of how many genes each instance of a Genome class has. Then I used them to make sure the array indexing doesn't go out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Your storage is good. Neither `pair` nor `array` requires indirect/dynamic allocation, so this is great for cache locality.

As for referencing elements, no, not exactly like that. You could have an enum with members `FIRST`, `SECOND` then pass that as another argument to `get_Genome`. But, honestly, this doesn't seem to me to be worthwhile.

Overall, your approach looks great to me. My only suggestions would be:

#### Re-use one `ofstream`

…rather than opening and closing the file for every sample. You should see substantial speed improvements from that change.

You could make one in your `main` or whatever, and have `write_Statistics` take a `std::ostream&`, which would also be more flexible!

#### Initialise a bit quicker

All those declarations in `init_Individual` *may* get optimised, but why take the risk? The following is pretty expressive:

```
genome Individual::init_Individual()
{
    const double a = -1.0;
    const double b =  0.0;

    return {{a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}, {a, b}};
}
```

It's worth noting here that your `double` initialisations were wrong: you were only initialising `a4` and `b4`; your compiler ought to have warned you about this. But, as shown, we don't need all of those anyway as they [are intended to] have the same values!

Comment: You're returning a bunch of undefined values. Nothing but `a4` and `b4` are definted.

Comment: @rsjaffe Great spot - that needs correcting as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use this. If I may ask, could you maybe expand a bit on the "reuse ofstream" part of your answer? I understand conceptually that you mean to write all the data in one single batch at the end, but I am not completely sure what that would look like. Some reference material to let me try it out myself would also be appreciated. Anyway, your answer is much appreciated!

Comment: @Matton968 That's not what I mean, no. I mean you create one `ofstream` then do lots of writes to it. Currently you open one `ofstream` per write, which is wasteful (because opening and closing files is expensive). Your book should have examples on how to do file-based I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what i meant in my comment by overloading the operator [].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>


class Genome {
    public:
        typedef std::pair<double, double> gene;

    private:
        double a1 = -1.0, a2 = -1.0, a3 = -1.0, a4 = -1.0;
        double b1 = 0.0, b2 = 0.0, b3 = 0.0, b4 = 0.0;

        gene g1{ a1,b1 };
        gene g2{ a2,b2 };
        gene g3{ a3,b3 };
        gene g4{ a4,b4 };

  public:
      Genome() {}

      const double operator[] (std::string l) const {
          if (l == "a1") {return g1.first;}
          else if (l == "b1") {return g1.second;}
          else if (l == "a2") {return g2.first;}
          else if (l == "b2") {return g2.second;}
          else if (l == "a3") {return g3.first;}
          else if (l == "b3") {return g3.second;}
          else if (l == "a4") {return g4.first;}
          else if (l == "b4") {return g4.second;}
          else {
              throw std::invalid_argument("not valid label");
          }
      }

      void setvalue(std::string l, double x) {
          if (l == "a1") {g1.first = x;}
          else if (l == "b1") {g1.second = x;}
          else if (l == "a2") {g2.first = x;}
          else if (l == "b2") {g2.second = x;}
          else if (l == "a3") {g3.first = x;}
          else if (l == "b3") {g3.second = x;}
          else if (l == "a4") {g4.first = x;}
          else if (l == "b4") {g4.second = x;}
          else {
              throw std::invalid_argument("not valid label");
          }
      }

    void write_Statistics(unsigned int counter) {
        std::ofstream ofs;
        ofs.open("data.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
        ofs << counter
        << std::setw(14) << (*this)["a1"] << std::setw(14) << (*this)["a2"]
        << std::setw(14) << (*this)["b1"] << std::setw(14) << (*this)["b2"] << "\n";
        ofs.close();
    }
    }
};
```

I don't know if you may find useful to access to the individual genes by a label instead of an index, but this is what this overload do.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Genome a = Genome();
    std::cout << a["b1"] << std::endl; #this prints 0

    a.setvalue("b2", 3.0);
    std::cout << a["b2"] << std::endl; #this prints 3

    a.write_Statistics(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an extremely costly way to do the object access. Why strings?! Why copied-around? And `Genome a = Genome();` should just be `Genome a;`